# How do you fill in a text field without a name? Ruby/Cucumber/Frank

Tags: ruby, cucumber, frank

My question is if it's possible to fill in a textfield that hasn't got a name. It has a Label with a name but the field itself doesn't have one. Is there a way of clicking at the label and the typing "blindly" or is this not possible?

This is how it looks in Frank inspect:

```
UITextField,
UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundView,
UIImageView,
UIImageView,
UIImageView,
UITextFieldLabel: Sök ort
```

This is what I have written:

When I fill in "Sök ort" with "paris"

And the code:

```
When /^I fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ironically i solved this a few minutes after the post.

here is the answer

Scenario Outline:

```
Search for Paris
    When I click on <variable>
    When I fill in with "paris"
```

Examples:

```
| variable |
| search |


When /^I click on search$/ do
    touch "view:'UITextFieldLabel' marked:'search'"
end

When /^I fill in with "([^\"]*)"$/ do
  type_into_keyboard("paris", :append_return => false)
end
```